# why cypress version 10 doesn't have chrome option in it

Tags: cypress

I am new to cypress. As for the latest version of cypress 10, when I run cypress open, it pop out below screen, having only two browsers option here. But I would like to use chrome to run my test.

**Problem:**

May I know how I can make the panel to show chrome option?

I already have had chrome installed

[image]

Coz I think the panel comes with no chrome is very strange, so I am not sure if it is something else problem. I also couldnt run the test after selecting Edge

[image]

This is my cypress config:

const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have chrome installed in your machine?
Cypress use the browsers that are locally installed by the user.

Comment: yes , i did, chrome is my default browser and have been using it as habit for long

Comment: Check if the chrome version is compatible with your cypress version. I use the last cypress version (v10.9.0) and the last chrome version(v107).